# Erro no primeiro scaffold em Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estou buscando aprender a programar em Ruby, criei o app, para tal, tive um erro já de início, onde tive que remover todos os HTTPS dos arquivos da pasta GEMFILE, mudando todos manualmente para HTTP, assim consegui criar o app.
Depois, fui criar o Scaffold, porém quando tento acessar, tenho o seguinte erro que não estou conseguindo saber o que está ocorrendo, quem puder ajudar, agradeço!

S.O: Windows 8.1 x64

[image: Erro ao tentar acessar o banco]

Comment: Consegui, seguindo essa dica:

Add to Gemfile

gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
then, run

bundle update coffee-script-source

Do seguinte link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312460/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-rails-windows-64bit?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No linux / osx ter o nodejs instalado resolve isso, sem precisar adicionar essa gem a cada projeto. Aliás, nos environments do gemfile, deixa isso só development.

Comment: Pô, funcionou mesmo! Acabei de testar aqui :)
Fiz um novo projeto, sem o Node.js, não funcionou, deu o mesmo erro, na sequência dei stop no server, instalei o Node.js, quando testei, funcionou normalmente, muito bom, obrigado, sendo assim, vou seguir com a versão mais recente do coffe.